# OmniAuth hash returns undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, omniauth

This is probably a very basic question but I have been looking at the code for quiete some time now and am not really understanding what is causing the no method error.

In my controller I have this

```
auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
@more = auth["provider"]
```

In my view I have this

```
<%= @more if @more != nil %>
```

For some reason I keep getting this error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
```

PS: I get the correct data if I were to `raise request.env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml`

Comment: Is `auth` sometimes `nil`, or only `auth["provider"]`?

Comment: I dont think so, see this [Example](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth?view=asciicast) from railscast

Comment: I see, but the only place you're using `[]` on an object is in your controller, so perhaps `auth` is being returned as `nil`.

Comment: Hmm thats a bit odd and strange.

Comment: When you do `raise request.env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml` a `provider` is present?

Comment: yeap I see a provider. This is a portion of the hash returned `!ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash provider: twitter uid: '961025947'`